# Using geneticsharp for solving multiobjective optimization problema

Tags: geneticsharp

Is it possible to use GeneticSharp to solve a custom multiobjective optimization problem?

I see that both IFitness and IChromosome are based on a double fitness. However, multiobjective problems have a list of double fitnesses. Nsga-II is a specialized genetic algorithm for solving such problems, but it shares many common steps with traditional genetic algorithms. Besides some specialized processing before generating an offspring in each evolution step, the key difference between nsga-ii and standards GAs is that two chromosomes are compared with the "dominance" operator, not a simple numeric "greater than" operator.

How could I implement Nsga-ii based on GeneticSharp? Can i extend the library or is it more appropriate to directly modify it (clone the repository and modify the interfaces and implementation)?

Comment: Please, can you show a sample code with what are the properties of your multidimensional chromosome?

Comment: The fitness is a list of doubles (List<double> ObjectiveValues), while the genes of an individual are binary-coded (a List<bool> genes, with fixed length). Objective values are calculated with a simulation software I developed.

Comment: I don't know NSGA-II, but seems you'll need directly modify GeneticSharp to support it. Seems this will a be great contribution to it. Please, pull-request it to GeneticSharp when it's done.

Comment: thanks! I will probably use Python's DEAP instead if I manage to set-up the C#/IronPython interaction. But I will definitely pull-request NSGA-II implementation for GeneticSharp if I develop it.

Comment: Multiobjective alghorithms will require a bit more than just a small modification, they will probably need a new GeneticAlgorithm class that returns a set of solutions not jus thte best chromosome. But a lot of the work on GS could be used... so I may revisit that too :)